# Don't know why my app is crashing

Tags: ios, swift, nsunknownkeyexception

I am very new to swift, *extremely* new, and I will probably feel like an idiot for asking this question. My very simple goal is that when my button is tapped the button's title will disappear, but unfortunately the app is crashing every time I run it and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for the help.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var background1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var screenButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.screenButton.setTitle("Tap!", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func screenTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.screenButton.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

}
```

```
2015-04-10 17:13:41.465 TopScore[6391:414281] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key screenTapped.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104fc0a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106b18bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104fc06b9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001053dbd43 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104f0a5e0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000105b1a4ed -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000105978a88 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000105979078 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001059792e9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010597977e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000105898509 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001058988a1 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001058a4f8c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010584f0c2 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2732
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000105851e3e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000105850d35 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001086ca243 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104ef5c7c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104eeb9c5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104eeb785 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104eeabc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001058507a2 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000105853580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  TopScore                            0x0000000104de1cee top_level_code + 78
    24  TopScore                            0x0000000104de1d2a main + 42
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001072f4145 start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: What type of exception? Which line? What is the message logged?

Comment: Please include the stack trace the comes up when the app crashes, it will make diagnosis easier!

Comment: @Erik Im really sorry about this man but where is the stack trace? When it crashes a load of different windows are popping up which make no sense to me.

Comment: Make sure you are debugging and check the console for a huge chunk of text.

Comment: On the top of your screen, where the apple icon is, in the toolbar, go to 'View'->'Debug Area'->'Activate Console' and get it to crash again, then in the debug console on the bottom right hand pane there will be a list of errors. Copy and paste that whole section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point, you accidentally set up an *outlet* called `screenTapped`. You need to find that outlet in Interface Builder in your storyboard and delete it.

What you want is an *action* from the button to `screenTapped:`. An action and an outlet are two very different things.

Comment: And see my book. Outlets: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_outlet_connections Actions: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_action_connections

Comment: you know this had to be a duplicate. It gets asked regularly. :)